# How to study the interaction between a set of nodes when the network is quite dense, using igraph?

Tags: r, networking, igraph

I have 4 undirected graph with 1000 vertices and 176672, 150994, 193477, 236060 edges. I am trying to see interaction between a specific set of nodes (16 in number) for each graph. This visualization in tkplot is not feasible as 1000 vertices is already way too much for it. I was thinking of if there is some way to extract the interaction of these 16 nodes from the parent graph and view separately, which will be then more easy to handle and work with in tkplot. I don't want the loss of information as in what is the node(s) in he path of interaction if it comes from other than 16 pre-specified nodes. Is there a way to achieve it?

Comment: Yes, this is called an induced subgraph, see `induced.subgraph`: http://igraph.org/r/doc/subgraph.html

Comment: I did this thing, but it does not show any of the nodes which were not pre-specified in case when the interaction between my 16 nodes is via some other node. Eg, if 7th node is interacting with 10th via 30th, I want that 30th too in my new graph. How can this be achieved?

Comment: So you want all connected components that include any of the 16 nodes? Then you can use the `clusters()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such a dense graph, if you only take the shortest paths connecting each pair of these 16 vertices, you will still get a graph too large for `tkplot`, or even to see any meaningful on a cairo pdf plot.
However, if you aim to do it, this is one possible way:

```
require(igraph)

g <- erdos.renyi.game(n = 1000, p = 0.1)

set <- sample(1:vcount(g), 16)

in.shortest.paths <- NULL
for(v in set){
    in.shortest.paths <- c(in.shortest.paths, 
        unlist(get.all.shortest.paths(g, from = v, to = set)$res))
}

subgraph <- induced.subgraph(g, unique(in.shortest.paths))
```

In this example, `subgraph` will include approx. half of all the vertices.

After this, I think you should consider to find some other way than visualization to investigate the relationships between your vertices of interest. It can be some topological metric, but it really depends on the aims of your analysis.

Comment: Thankyou! @Gabor 
I agree, this is quite dense. My aim is about studying the interaction between 16 nodes, which are actually disease genes, so i ought to see how the genes are interacting in four network that i am comparing. So, to improve my results/study the interaction, i should of some other way.

Comment: @deeenes- Sorry, i am not able to edit my comment, I want to include you too in that, and i also want to say Thankyou for helping and giving a direction.

Comment: thanks for accepting my answer!as i do also bioinformatics, i am wondering why is your gene interaction network so dense? perhaps it is from large high-throughput screenings, or in silico prediction, which results high ratio of false positives. in this case, you might consider to look for other sources of prior knowledge, to build a better network, or filter the edges a biologically meaningful way. i think ideally a molecular network should have an average degree of 5-10.

Comment: my work is on DNA microarray data, and i am working on finding coexpressing genes in 4 disease states using candidate gene approach. For me degree of nodes is quite high, if u say average value be 5-10, i have it in hundreds. At this point, i have 1000 coexpressing genes, but if i will increase the number, i will run into some serious problems of visualisation. Yes, i need to refine my data as you said. I will look into more resources on how to achieve that, or perhaps you can provide some links as a start!